# Calculating RMSE for Simulated Linear Regression

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

I am trying to calculate the RMSE for the simulated data. But the output gives NaN for the RMSE. Below is the code I am using.

```
library(caret)
RMSE <- function(x,y) sqrt(mean((x-y)^2))
sim.regression<-function(n.obs=200,coefficients=c(3,1.5,0,0,2,0,0,0),s.deviation=.1){
  
  n.var=length(coefficients)  
  M=matrix(0,ncol=n.var,nrow=n.obs)
  
  beta=as.matrix(coefficients)
  
  for (i in 1:n.var){
    M[,i]=rnorm(n.obs,0,1)
  }
  
  y=M %*% beta + rnorm(n.obs,0,s.deviation)
  
  train.data<-y[1:150]
  train.data<-data.frame(train.data)
  test.data<-y[151:200]
  test.data<-data.frame(test.data)
  prediction <- predict(lm(y~M),test.data)
  RMSE.data<-RMSE(prediction, test.data$y)
  
  return (list(x=M,y=y,coeff=coefficients, RMSE=RMSE.data))
  
}

set.seed(2000)
sim.regression(100)
```

Comment: Try just running the code in your function line by line. You can also use the debugger. There seem to be several problems with how you are structuring data. You seem to have `test.data$y` when that column doesn't exist. Also your `lm` model seems to have `M` as the independent variable but you aren't passing that in with `test.data` so you can't make predictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. There were few issues in the code:

- Assuming that you are trying to learn/predict 'y' based on 'M', you have to combine M and y and make a data frame.
- After that only, you should split first 150 for train and remaining for test.
- Then you train on `train.data` and predict on `test.data`
- Also, since you have hardcoded [1:150] and [150:200] for train-test split, you will have to pass `200` as in sim.regression(200).

Corrected code below:

```
library(caret)
RMSE <- function(x,y) sqrt(mean((x-y)^2))
sim.regression<-function(n.obs=200,coefficients=c(3,1.5,0,0,2,0,0,0),s.deviation=.1){
  
  n.var=length(coefficients)  
  M=matrix(0,ncol=n.var,nrow=n.obs)
  
  beta=as.matrix(coefficients)
  
  for (i in 1:n.var){
    M[,i]=rnorm(n.obs,0,1)
  }
  
  y=M %*% beta + rnorm(n.obs,0,s.deviation)
  data<-data.frame(M,y)
  train.data <- data[1:150,]
  test.data<-data[151:200,]
  prediction <- predict(lm(y~., data=train.data),test.data)
  RMSE.data<-RMSE(prediction, test.data$y)
  return (list(x=M,y=y,coeff=coefficients, RMSE=RMSE.data))
  
}

set.seed(2000)
sim.regression(200)
```

Prints:

```
$RMSE
0.0755869850491716
```